# Different outputs when using Seq.map and Array.map for the same code in F#

Tags: f#

I have a simple event-based implementation of FizzBuzz as follows

```
// Events in F#

type FizzBuzz() =
    let _event = Event<int>()

    member this.Event = _event.Publish
    member this.Check n = _event.Trigger n 

// Instantiate
let fizzBuzzer = FizzBuzz()

// Add an event handler
fizzBuzzer.Event.Add (function
    | x when x%5=0 && x%3=0 -> printfn "FizzBuzz"
    | x when x%3=0 -> printfn "Fizz"
    | x when x%5=0 -> printfn "Buzz"
    | x -> printfn "%d" x)
```

When I test it using `[|1..15|] |> Array.map fizzBuzzer.Check` I get the expected output:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
val it : unit [] =
  [|(); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); (); ()|]
```

However, when I test it with `[1..15] |> Seq.map fizzBuzzer.Check`, I have

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
val it : seq<unit> = seq [(); (); (); (); ...]
```

I don't understand why the two outputs should be different.

Comment: Short version: use `Seq.iter()` rather than `Seq.map()` since you want the side-effects. Long version coming soon, as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

F# sequences are *lazy*, so they're only iterated as far as needed by the consuming code. When you use the `Seq.map` function, it produces a lazy sequence that has not been iterated yet. When F# Interactive gets a sequence as the result of an expression, it deliberately does not print the whole sequence, because the sequence might be infinite, or might take a long time to compute. Instead, it grabs the first **four** elements of the sequence, and prints them. Then it checks whether the sequence has any more values (i.e., the `.MoveNext()` function on the sequence's enumerator returned `true`), and if so, it prints `...` at the end. So the sequence will actually have five values calculated, although you'll only see four of them.

If you actually want to force the entire sequence to execute (because you want its side-effects, like printing to the screen, to run), then you should use `Seq.iter` instead of `Seq.map`. Note that `Seq.iter` only accepts functions that return `()` (that is, the `unit` type), which makes it clear that it's looking for functions with side-effects rather than functions with meaningful return values.

Answer (score 5):

`Seq.map` creates a lazy sequence whose elements aren't evaluated until the are used. As you can see, the `toString` method shows only the first four elements of the sequence followed by `...`. It does this because sequences can be infinite (and there's no way to tell), so if it always tried to show all elements, that might lead to an infinite loop. Since it only shows the four first elements, it only needs to evaluate those four plus the fifth one (in order to decide whether to display the `...`, I imagine). So those are the only times your function is executed until you iterate over the whole sequence.

`Array.map` on the other hand creates an array, which is a strict data structure. So all the elements of the array exist the moment the array is created.

Generally speaking the function given to `map` does not usually have side-effects (or at least not externally visible ones), so when exactly each invocation of the function is evaluated, should not matter. Of course, that's very much not the case here.

Further there's very little use in having an array or a sequence of units. Clearly you're more interested in the side-effects of calling your function than you are in its return values. So instead of using `map` to create an array or sequence of values that you're not interested in, you should be using `Seq.iter` to call your function on all elements of the original array without creating any new data structure.

Or alternatively you could use `map` to create an array or sequence of strings instead of units.